# Ionic app size is over 60MB

Tags: ionic3

I have developed a couple Ionic 3 apps and have compiled an iOS version.

The ipa file is over 60 Mb, even for the simplest app.

This seems extremely large for a mobile app.

In one app I do have a few image files, but they are all svg.

Does this sound right to everyone, or am I missing something when I compile?

Comment: check unnecessary files again. Did you try `ionic cordova build ios/android --prod --release`

Comment: Hi Berk, I tried that and it cut the size in half to 32Mb. It still seems pretty big considering there is very little code and only 5Mb in the assets folder. Any other thoughts on how to reduce size? Thanks!

Comment: try ionic cordova plugin list
command to check if there is any unwanted plugin exist remove that and try to build the app with --prod mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution could be :

```
ionic cordova build ios/android --prod --release --optimizejs --minifyjs --minifycss
```

Also remove all plugins that you don't use.
For example a simple app of 1 MB, becomes 11 just becouse i use a paypal plugin.

So I suggest you:

1. Compress all screenshots & app icons (splash and icons, generate
   them with ionic cordova resouurces)
2. http://www.minifier.org/
3. comands for optimization
4. and also "Special Instruction For iOS: 5 — Once you archive, Open
   Organizer, right click on the desired archive, click on “show in
   finder” You will find “*.xcarchive”. Right click on it “Show package
   contents”-> product -> application -> “your app name” -> “Show
   package contents”

   You can even remove unwanted files from here too. Later upload it to
   app store"